# Where are the default font preferences in a modern Unix desktop stored (those which affect the choice of the font by an uncustomized Emacs 24)?

Tags: xfce, emacs, fonts, gsettings, altlinux

My situation and my question are like the ones in http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2012-06/msg00183.html:

> after the recent upgrade to emacs 24.x (...) my font size
>   is too large (one times C-x C-minus corrects it temporarily for the
>   buffer). The menu font size is fine, the rest (buffer, mode line,
>   minibuffer is too large). I've read about the various ways to set the
>   font size.
>
> **Is there a specific reason why the font size has increased after the
>   update? And thus a global way to correct it?**

So, even having read about all the ways to set a font in Emacs, I haven't found an answer which would explain the difference in font size between an uncustomized Emacs 23.x and Emacs 24.y.

Probably, it's as in that answer:

> Emacs 24 adds support for gconf and gsettings, so it'll pick whatever
>   monospace font and sizes you have set as the default in your system
>   settings

I'd like to know the place these settings are stored, and to tweak them (so that not only Emacs, but perhaps other similarly behaving programs would get my font settings).

I'm especially interested in making the default font size smaller again.

(Now, I'm using Xfce.)

Comment: The site emacs.stackexchange.com would be a better fit for this question, I think. You can check on whether this is the case, if you want, on the emacs.stackexchange chat site, namely http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17392/scratch. This question is on-topic here, but emacs.sx is a specialist site, so it is a more natural fit, provided it is on topic, imo.

Comment: @Faheem Thanks! I have just noticed that there is such site. After some thought about this, I think that my question is about the modern Unix environment (around Emacs), rather than a peculiarity of Emacs itself, so this site must be a better place. It's a question for all modern Unix users with X desktops: where are the default font preferences stored? (And Emacs simply uses them.)

Comment: Did you try with `~/.Xresources`? Just put there something like `Emacs.font: DejaVu Sans Mono 10`